# Transform breaks Object

Tags: modeling, mesh

I was trying to move a model I had downloaded but when I grabbed it on the z axis this happened.

[image: problem]
before
[image]

Comment: Hi. Uh... what happened? Please explain and also add an image of your model, before you moved it by [editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/137143/edit) your question.

Comment: I suspect your model is bound to an armature with an armature modifier. If you look in the modifiers tab (blue wrench icon), is there an armature modifier there?

Comment: thank you so much! that was the problem.